# update table for multiple users

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to count the number of times 'yes' in present for a user in a table, then post the result into anther table for that same user.  Both tables have the username.  I would like this done for each user.  I have the following but it is not working.

```
$sql = $item_count = "SELECT SUM(if(strike='yes',1,0)) AS strike_total FROM weekpicks WHERE username = 'username'";
      // execute SQL query and get result
      $sql_result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
      if (!$sql_result) {
          echo "Something has gone wrong!";
      } 
      else {
           //loop through record and get values
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result)) {

        $item_result = ($row = @mysql_query($item_count)) or die(mysql_error());
        $strike_total = ($row = @mysql_result($item_result,"strike_total"));
        $strikes = ($row = $strike_total ['strike_total']);
        $username = $row["username"];


        // the following will insert number of strikes into table for each user.
        $sql = "UPDATE authorize SET strikes  = '($strikes)' WHERE username='$username'";

        //mysql_query(" UPDATE authorize SET " . "strikes = '" . ($strikes) . "' WHERE username='$username' ");
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: What happens in your code? Error message? Wrong number inserted? Page freezes?

Comment: Stop using MySQL. It's gone as of PHP 7 and deprecated in lower versions. Switch to PDO or MySQLi. Also, we need more info for us to help you.

Comment: nothing is posted, just a blank screen when I load it or refresh it.  If I test it in myphpadmin the result is " "

Comment: If I replace the WHERE username = 'BOB' then it will work for just BOB only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one query should be enough

Update for single user..

```
UPDATE authorize SET strikes  = (select count(*) from weekpicks WHERE username = '$username' and strike='yes') WHERE username='$username';
```

For bulk update all users

```
UPDATE authorize as A SET strikes  = (select count(*) from weekpicks B WHERE strike='yes' and A.username=B.username group by B.username)
```

Isn't that simple.

Comment: What's the error its giving? Just updated a small thing in my answer.. Try again with the new query.

Comment: If I put Bob where $username is then it only works for Bob

Comment: aah I get it.. you want a bulk update for all users.